# Google Analytics number of sessions vs Screen Views for my Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

Does the following screenshots from GA make any sense? I thought a session could contains multiple screen views, thus Screens / Sessions should be greater than 1?

Did I understand it wrong? what could I do wrong to get these weird numbers[image]?

Comment: Hi @sean have you resolved this issue as i am facing the same issue

Comment: did u find any answer ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions):

> By default, Google Analytics will group hits that are received within
>   30 minutes of one another into the same session. This period is
>   configurable at the property level.

So, if a session was set to expire after, say, 10 seconds and the phone was just lying around with the app running for 1 hour, it would generate 360 sessions for 1 screen view.